# my code execution is having a logic error with this API

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am currently working on building an IMGUR uploader for Windows Phone, and adapting code I found in the following tutorial: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/building-imgur-client-windows-3

My code is mostly the same as this person's with minor differences that appeal to what I currently am doing. The app allows the user to pick a picture of theirs, and it gets converted into byte[] when the Upload button is clicked, which also executes my method UploadImage. I did a breakpoint and found out my program is skipping a huge chunk of my code, for god knows why. I probably screwed up somewhere, so I would like another set of eyes on it. I'll indicate the portion being skipped.

```
    private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //First, convert the image to byte array so we can proceed.
        MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
        WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(bmp);
        wbmp.SaveJpeg(mStream, wbmp.PixelWidth, wbmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
        mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        data = mStream.GetBuffer();

        this.UploadImage(data);
        lblImageURL.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        lblImageURL.Text = finalImageURL;

    }


    public void UploadImage(byte[] content, Action<bool> onCompletion = null)
    {
        string boundary = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string header = string.Format("--{0}", boundary);
        string footer = string.Format("--{0}--", boundary);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.imgur.com/3/upload");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Client-ID " + clientID;
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data, boundary=" + boundary;

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        string base64string = Convert.ToBase64String(content);

        builder.AppendLine(header);
        builder.AppendLine("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"");
        builder.AppendLine();
        builder.AppendLine(base64string);
        builder.AppendLine(footer);

        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString());

        **BEGIN AREA THAT IS BEING SKIPPED FOR SOME REASON**
        request.BeginGetRequestStream((result) =>
            {
                using (Stream s = request.EndGetRequestStream(result))
                {
                    s.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }

                request.BeginGetResponse((respResult) =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(respResult);
                            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                            {
                                imageURL = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                Regex regex = new Regex(@"https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?");
                                MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(imageURL);
                                foreach (Match match in matches)
                                {
                                    finalImageURL = match.Value;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (WebException ex)
                        {
                            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
                            {
                                imageURL = "An uploading error occured. Please check your connection.";
                            }
                        }
                    }, null);
            }, null);
    }
    **END SKIPPED AREA**
}
```

So, yeah. It skips a lot of stuff, no idea why...

Comment: So it gets to the `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` line and then skips everything after that?  Is the `GetBytes()` method throwing an exception?

Comment: You should also post your exact code and not just something similar.

Comment: No exceptions, goes past that GetBytes() line just fine, and skips everything after that. Edited in now the exact code, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing debug of asynchronous operation. When you set breakpoint on request.BeginGetRequestStream line it won't debug it, but if you set it in the inner block -

```
using(Stream s = request.EndGetRequestStream(result))
```

Then it will debug it fine.

There is another problem. Currently you sent request, and update finalImageURL variable in the async callback, and method btnUpload_Click won't wait while it completes. So finalImageURL will be updated much lately that btnUpload_Click method finishes execution.

As for me you need to rewrite it to sync code like this:

```
public void UploadImage(byte[] content)
{
    string boundary = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    string header = string.Format("--{0}", boundary);
    string footer = string.Format("--{0}--", boundary);

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.imgur.com/3/upload");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Client-ID " + clientID;
    request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data, boundary=" + boundary;

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    string base64string = Convert.ToBase64String(content);

    builder.AppendLine(header);
    builder.AppendLine("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"");
    builder.AppendLine();
    builder.AppendLine(base64string);
    builder.AppendLine(footer);

    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString());

    using (Stream s = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        s.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    try
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var imageURL = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?");
            MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(imageURL);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                finalImageURL = match.Value;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            imageURL = "An uploading error occured. Please check your connection.";
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can just call it in sync way from btnUpload_Click handler, but UI can hangs during it. Or you can reuse async keyword from .Net 4.5, or Tasks from .Net 4. Here is example async logic with Tasks:

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //First, convert the image to byte array so we can proceed.
    MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
    WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(bmp);
    wbmp.SaveJpeg(mStream, wbmp.PixelWidth, wbmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
    mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var data = mStream.GetBuffer();

    // sync way
    this.UploadImage(data);
    lblImageURL.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    lblImageURL.Text = finalImageURL;

    // or async way that is better for UI operations
    Task.Factory.
         StartNew(() => this.UploadImage(data)).
         ContinueWith((task) =>
                      {                                                                                                                             
                       lblImageURL.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                       lblImageURL.Text = finalImageURL;
                      });
}
```

**UPDATE1**

I didn't noticed WindowsPhone tag. Yeah, it makes sense. You can update it like this.
Basically you can mass two anonymous methods to UploadImage method. First one will be called by method when it gets finalImageUrl. Second one will be called when an error happens. Both of them will be executed in async way, when request will be completed in background.

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs  e)
{
    //First, convert the image to byte array so we can proceed.
    MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
    //WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(bmp);
    //wbmp.SaveJpeg(mStream, wbmp.PixelWidth, wbmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
    mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var data = mStream.GetBuffer();

            this.UploadImage(
                data,
                (url) =>
                {
                                        // this will be called on success result
                    lblImageURL.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                    lblImageURL.Text = url;
                },
                () =>
                {

                     // display some error message to user that image failed to upload
                });

}

public void UploadImage(byte[] content, Action<string> onCompletion, Action onError)
{
    string boundary = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    string header = string.Format("--{0}", boundary);
    string footer = string.Format("--{0}--", boundary);

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.imgur.com/3/upload");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Client-ID " + clientID;
    request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data, boundary=" + boundary;

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    string base64string = Convert.ToBase64String(content);

    builder.AppendLine(header);
    builder.AppendLine("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"");
    builder.AppendLine();
    builder.AppendLine(base64string);
    builder.AppendLine(footer);

    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString());

    //**BEGIN AREA THAT IS BEING SKIPPED FOR SOME REASON**
    request.BeginGetRequestStream((result) =>
        {
            using (Stream s = request.EndGetRequestStream(result))
            {
                s.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            request.BeginGetResponse((respResult) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(respResult);
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            var imageURL = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            Regex regex = new Regex(@"https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?");
                            MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(imageURL);
                            foreach (Match match in matches)
                            {
                                var finalImageURL = match.Value;
                                onCompletion(finalImageURL);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (WebException ex)
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            onError();
                            imageURL = "An uploading error occured. Please check your connection.";
                        }
                    }
                }, null);
        }, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this code, I am working on implementing it now! I did have a question, though. I'm using the Windows Phone 8 SDK, and HttpWebRequest does not have definitions for GetResponse() and GetRequestStream(). I'm sort of a novice at all this, so can you perhaps point me in the right direction of figuring out how to make this code work with Windows Phone?

Comment: Basically the code has to be async because WP only has Asynchronous methods under HttpWebRequest. Your code is Sync so WP SDK doesn't have definitions for GetResponse() and GetRequestStream()

Comment: I updated answer. I didn't worked with WP8 SDK, so i didn't know that it has't sync operations. In updated version there is a sample of method with callbacks, that should work in WP8

Comment: Your updated code works! My only issue now appears to be an internal error on Imgur's side, which I will contact their developers about. Thank you so much for the help!